# Async Grizzly with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, grizzly

I'm new to both Grizzly and Spring Security.

I'm trying to implement an oAuth 2 Resource and Authentication server and would like to use the spring implementation. Assuming that the server would receive a big number of requests I'd want the server to handle the request asynchronously. Is this possible?

Currently i'm following [GitHub](https://github.com/BangBoy/Grizzly-Jersey-Spring-Spring-Security/blob/master/src/main/java/example/gjss/Gjss.java) which is using grizzly-webserver, which if i'm not mistaken is synchronous.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "async". What is your expectation?

Comment: I do not want that a request blocks a thread.